# What does this function ft_isalnum do?

Tags: c++, c

I am reading a program which contains the following function, which is

```
int ft_isalnum(int c)
{
    return ((c >= 'a' && c <= 'z') || (c >= 'A' && c <= 'Z')
            || (c >= '0' && c <= '9'));
}
```

I don't quite understand what does this function intend to do?

Comment: The name of the function should give you a clue: `alnum == alphanumeric`.

Comment: It is intended to mimic the library function `isalnum`.

Comment: Not sure why someone would write something like that since there is `isalnum()` in `<ctype.h>`

Comment: And it is doing so poorly.  Not sure about C but C++ does not require a-z characters to be in a range.

Comment: @NathanOliver C also does not require a-z or A-Z to be a range. Most notably, in EBCDIC, '}' and '\' are both between 'A' and 'Z'

Comment: @joelw Thanks for the conformation.

Comment: @NathanOliver C doesn't have it either.

Comment: @Swordfish, It could be due to `isalnum`'s contract where the argument must fit in `unsigned char` or be `EOF`.

Comment: @chris so what would be the problem with `int ft_isalnum(int c) { return isalnum((unsigned) c); }` ?

Comment: @Swordfish, Assuming you meant `(unsigned char)c`, nothing that I can see. I'd personally prefer making use of the existing implementation instead of redoing it from scratch.

Comment: @chris "I'd personally prefer making use of the existing implementation instead of redoing it from scratch." Thats what I wanted to show with the one-liner in my last comment: have a function you can feed `int`s which uses the standard library appropriately.

Comment: @Swordfish it could be a frestanding implementation that doesn't provide ctype.h; or perhaps the vendor one is buggy or uses an undesirable amount of resources

Comment: @M.M You are right, of course. Could all hold true. I'm just too spoiled by my fat desktop.

Answer (score 3):

As suggested by its name, the function checks if the given character is alphanumeric.

Assuming ASCII character encoding where A-Z and a-z are stored consecutively, it checks if the character is in either the 'A' to 'Z' range, the 'a' to 'z' range, or the '0' to '9' range and returns true if any of those conditions are satisfied.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: @Boris Glad I could help.  Feel free to [accept this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) if you found it useful.

Answer (score 2):

Write a program to figure it out:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int ft_isalnum(int c)
{
    return ((c >= 'a' && c <= 'z') || (c >= 'A' && c <= 'Z') || (c >= '0' && c <= '9'));
}

int main(void)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 128; putchar(++i % 8 ? ' ' : '\n'))
        printf("%3d '%c' %c ", i, isprint((char unsigned)i) ? i : '?', ft_isalnum(i) ? 'X' : ' ');  
    putchar('\n');
}
```

**Output**

```
  0 '?'      1 '?'      2 '?'      3 '?'      4 '?'      5 '?'      6 '?'      7 '?'
  8 '?'      9 '?'     10 '?'     11 '?'     12 '?'     13 '?'     14 '?'     15 '?'
 16 '?'     17 '?'     18 '?'     19 '?'     20 '?'     21 '?'     22 '?'     23 '?'
 24 '?'     25 '?'     26 '?'     27 '?'     28 '?'     29 '?'     30 '?'     31 '?'
 32 ' '     33 '!'     34 '"'     35 '#'     36 '$'     37 '%'     38 '&'     39 '''
 40 '('     41 ')'     42 '*'     43 '+'     44 ','     45 '-'     46 '.'     47 '/'
 48 '0' X   49 '1' X   50 '2' X   51 '3' X   52 '4' X   53 '5' X   54 '6' X   55 '7' X
 56 '8' X   57 '9' X   58 ':'     59 ';'     60 ''     63 '?'
 64 '@'     65 'A' X   66 'B' X   67 'C' X   68 'D' X   69 'E' X   70 'F' X   71 'G' X
 72 'H' X   73 'I' X   74 'J' X   75 'K' X   76 'L' X   77 'M' X   78 'N' X   79 'O' X
 80 'P' X   81 'Q' X   82 'R' X   83 'S' X   84 'T' X   85 'U' X   86 'V' X   87 'W' X
 88 'X' X   89 'Y' X   90 'Z' X   91 '['     92 '\'     93 ']'     94 '^'     95 '_'
 96 '`'     97 'a' X   98 'b' X   99 'c' X  100 'd' X  101 'e' X  102 'f' X  103 'g' X
104 'h' X  105 'i' X  106 'j' X  107 'k' X  108 'l' X  109 'm' X  110 'n' X  111 'o' X
112 'p' X  113 'q' X  114 'r' X  115 's' X  116 't' X  117 'u' X  118 'v' X  119 'w' X
120 'x' X  121 'y' X  122 'z' X  123 '{'    124 '|'    125 '}'    126 '~'    127 '?'
```

The output indicates, on my machine, that characters `0` to `9` and letters `A` to `Z` and `a` to `z` `return` a `1` while everything else `return`s a `0`.

**Note**

Not all characters are printable.

**Thanks**

To @Swordfish for making the output more attractive and readable.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: Would you mind if I'd edit your answer to have better readable output?

Comment: @FiddlingBits I hope you are ok with that.

Comment: @Swordfish Looks great!